# Searching for a string in a json file and extracting its section

Tags: python, json, nested

I was wondering how to perform the following:
1.search for strings in a json and extract their nested components.
given:

```
"type": "blah",
"animals": [
    {
        "type": "dog1",
        "name": "oscar",
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "dog2",
        "name": "John",
        }
    },
    {
        "type": "cat1",
        "name": "Fred",
        "Colors": [
            "Red"
        ],
        "Contact_info": [
            {
                "Owner": "Jill",
                "Owner_number": "123"
            }
        ],
    
    },
    {
        "type": "cat3",
        "name": "Freddy",
        "Colors": [
            "Blue"
        ],
        "Contact_info": [
            {
                "Owner": "Ann",
                "Owner_number": "1323"
            }
        ],
```

From this json, I would like to extract all of the animals that are of type cat like cat1 and cat2, as well as all of the information within that block. Like if I search for cat it should return:

```
{
    "type": "cat1",
    "name": "Fred",
    "Colors": [
        "Red"
    ],
    "Contact_info": [
        {
            "Owner": "Jill",
            "Owner_number": "123"
        }
    ],

},
{
    "type": "cat3",
    "name": "Freddy",
    "Colors": [
        "Blue"
    ],
    "Contact_info": [
        {
            "Owner": "Ann",
            "Owner_number": "1323"
        }
    ],
```

Not necessarily that format, but just all of the information that has type cat. Im trying to  search for objects in a json file and extract features from that search as well as anything nested inside of it.
Here is my code so far:

````
f = open('data.json')
 
# returns JSON object as
# a dictionary
data = json.load(f)
 
# Iterating through the json
# list
for i in data:
    if i['type'] == 'cat':
        print(i['name'])
        print(i['colors'])

        break
 
# Closing file
f.close()```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### To begin with, I recommend using the **`with` statement** that creates a runtime context that allows you to run a group of statements under the control of a context manager.

It’s much more readable and allows you to skip closing the file since the context manager will do everything for you.

##### Moving to your problem

Suppose your file is called `animals.json`

```py
# Import json library to work with json files
import json

# Use context manager
with open("animals.json", "rb") as f:
    # Load animals list from json file
    animals = json.load(f)["animals"]

# Create a list of dictionaries if animal type contains "cat"
cats = [animal for animal in animals if "cat" in animal.get("type")]

# Write data to cats.json
json.dump(cats, open("cats.json", "w"), indent=4, sort_keys=False, ensure_ascii=False)
```

This code outputs the formatted `cats.json` file with all necessary elements:

```
[
    {
        "type": "cat1",
        "name": "Fred",
        "Colors": [
            "Red"
        ],
        "Contact_info": [
            {
                "Owner": "Jill",
                "Owner_number": "123"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "cat3",
        "name": "Freddy",
        "Colors": [
            "Blue"
        ],
        "Contact_info": [
            {
                "Owner": "Ann",
                "Owner_number": "1323"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```